# Server Side Includes syntax no longer works with Apache 2.4

Tags: ssi, server-side-includes

I am using this syntax to check for the current document name with *Server Side Includes (SSI)*:

```
<!--#if expr="$DOCUMENT_NAME = /index.shtml/" -->
    <ul id="menu">
        ...
    </ul>
<!--#endif -->
```

Unfortunately, this no longer works with Apache 2.4 (it used to work with version 2.2, though!).

What am I missing here? How can I get this to work?

Comment: did you try to use the v function Like: `<!--#if expr='v("DOCUMENT_NAME")= /index.shtml/' -->` ?

Comment: And did you try this one too `<!--#if expr='"$DOCUMENT_NAME" = "/index.shtml/"' -->` as I can found it in apache 2.4 docs.

Comment: @MohamedBdr: Yes, I tried both of those but to no avail... :-(